# UIScrollView to display several UIViews with paging

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I just wanted to clarify how to accomplish a certain effect using UIScrollView.

I want to have about 10 separate views (which are full size) scrollable with paging through one UIScrollView. The views have dynamic content. I want it to feel a bit like a book.

Would the best way of accomplishing this to be to have one main view controller with a UIScrollView that loads several UIViews which are linked into the view controller as IBOutlets (the views being separate .nib files)? Would it be best if I only loaded the views flanking the current view (i.e. three views in total) to avoid loading too much into memory? Also...is it possible to achieve using this using more than one view controller ie. having a view controller per each of the views in the scroll view?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do it with a UIScrollView, however I would suggest just using a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) instead, since that offers the behavior you want (feels like a book).

If you want to go the UIScrollView way then you can take a look at this sample code from apple: [Scrolling example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023)

Comment: Is it legal to use that control in an iPhone-sized app?